# Ajax request not working for dynamic control append

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2

I have referred [Steven Sanderson's blog](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) and tried to implement dynamically insertion of controls on link's click event. Now in my case, It is not working. I don't know what's wrong with it. Deletion of Div (Including controls) is working fine. But Appending controls not working. When I click on 'Add More' link it open on new Page. Not render adding controls on same page.

My MainView Code:

```
<div id="Div1">
  <% Html.RenderAction("_EditServices", "CRM", new { id = Model.Id });%>
</div>
<div id="editorRows">
  <% Html.RenderAction("_EditInsertServices", "CRM"); %>
</div>
<%= Html.ActionLink("+ Add More Service(s)", "EditAdd", null , new { id = "addItem" })%>
```

My PartiaView for _EditInsertServices:

```
<div class="editorRow">
<% using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("services"))
  { %>
  NOS:<%:Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.Id,(SelectList)ViewData["crmServiceType"] as SelectList,"---")%>
  Comment:<%=Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Comment, new { size = "20" })%>
  <a class="deleteInsertRow">delete</a>
  <% } %>
</div>
```

My Controller code:

```
public ActionResult EditAdd()
{
  ViewData["crmServiceType"] = new SelectList(CRMRequestDL.GetCRM_Service_TypeList().ToArray(), "Id", "ServiceName");
  return View("_EditInsertServices", new CommentedService());
}
public ActionResult _EditInsertServices()
{
  ViewData["crmServiceType"] = new SelectList(CRMRequestDL.GetCRM_Service_TypeList().ToArray(), "Id", "ServiceName");
  return PartialView();
}
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#addItem").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) { $("#editorRows").append(html); }
        });
        return false;
    });
    $("a.deleteInsertRow").live("click", function () {
        $(this).parents("div.editorRow:first").remove();
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What version of jQuery do you use ?

Comment: Did you check in the console 1) you have no error 2) the requested pages are correctly received ?

Comment: @dystroy, I am not getting any error expect "ReferenceError: $ is not defined" while I click on Add More Link. I think there might be a problem in Html.ActionLink. My jquery version is 1.9

Comment: So clearly you can't use `live`.

Comment: @dystroy, I tried on but it's not working. But Live is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Actually I put $("#addItem").click(function (){}); function into $(document).ready(function () {}); function and it works fine.
So whenever I use $("any class/ id"), I should put that method within **$(document).ready()** function.

Here is the solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#addItem").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
    url: this.href,
    cache: false,
    success: function (html) { $("#editorRows").append(html); }});
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

live() is deprecated and is removed in jQuery 1.9

use `on`

```
  $('#editorRows').on("click", "a.deleteInsertRow",function () {
    $(this).parents("div.editorRow:first").remove();
    return false;
});
```

if you want to [read](http://jq4you.blogspot.com/2013/02/jquery-direct-and-delegate-on-event.html) more about on events

Comment: My adding controls not working. Removal of Div is working fine.